# Log backup Job disable and enable during FULL backup -Sql Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am planning to test the Sql server migration of Production databases but i am thinking to stop TLog Backup job during Backup and Restore as I don't need TLog backup and my Backup and Restore process might be done by that time.
Is it hurt anything like Log sequence or breaking log chain or is it safe to disable (stop) and enable (Turn ON) during Migration process?

Sql server: 2008R2
Recovery Model: FULL

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you're just testing migration, no need to stop Transaction Log backups. Maybe something will happen during your testing period, and you'll lose data between this period of time.

If you'll disable T-Log backups without changing Recovery Mode to Simple, you will not brake the T-Log backup chain. After enabling them again, new T-Log will resume the same backup chain.

Comment: Thanks Elvin. I will be using DMA for migration but not sure it's using COPY_ONLY Backup or not. Even though If I use DMA then it will not hurt any Log chain or sequence, right?  I am not intending to disable the TLog job but trying to avoid any side effect for Log chain but I am not going to change the Recovery Model as will be keeping FULL so it will be fine, right?

Comment: I'm not sure which type of backups will use DMA while migration, but if you'll have full backup before starting migrations testing and plus following T-Log backups, no matter DMA will take FULL backup with COPY_ONLY option or not, in case of disaster, you can restore your FULL+T-Log backups without any problem.